# Subscription SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, report, subscription

I need help to disable the Subscription tab when the users view the report please.
How do I enable Subscription tab to a certain users.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like their rights need to be edited in Report Manager, to remove their options to manage subscriptions.